# Why would the pH of a solution not be 7 at the equivalence point of an acid-base titration?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, acid-base, experimental-chemistry, ph

Is it because the new substance formed might be acidic/basic ?
The internet defines this point as when the number of moles of the acid equals the number of moles of the base. But if we have for example 1 mole of NaOH and 1 mole of H2SO4 (both in dilute solutions) mixed together, the resulting solution will still be acidic because 1 mole of H2SO4 releases 2 moles of H+ right ? So we will have an extra mole of H+ which will make the resulting mixture acidic. So is this still the equivalence point even though it isnt really equal (bcz we have 1 extra mole of H+) or is it 1 mole of NaOH + half a mole of H2SO4 ?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence point is defined as when you have an equal amount of acid and base. It you have a strong acid and a strong base, the pH at the equivalence point should be pretty close to 7, but if you have a weak acid or a weak base involved, there is not reason why the equivalence point should be at pH 7. You would have a conjugate base or acid that is reasonably basic or acidic at the equivalence point.